# How can we use spring security Ldap for authenticating with angularjs as client side

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I have created an application using spring-mvc and angularjs. For authentication, I have created a table in database and I am matching the user enter against the users in database. But now I want to do authentication using LDAP. Can someone help me out with how to do LDAP authentication with angularjs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the spring docs about ldap authentication- http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/ ? Or even this guide - https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I've used LDAP authentication with Spring MVC and AngularJs in my application, here is what I've come up with...

securityContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="contextSource"
          class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
        <property name="anonymousReadOnly" value="false"/>
        <property name="password" value="${ldap.password}"/>
        <property name="pooled" value="false"/>
        <property name="userDn" value="${ldap.userdn}"/>
        <property name="base" value="${ldap.base}"/>
        <property name="referral" value="follow"/>
        <property name="urls">
            <list>
                <value>${ldap.url}</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entryPoint" class="com.company.ldap.UserAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

    <bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="com.company.ldap.LdapLogoutSuccessHandler"/>

    <bean id="userDetailsContextMapper" class="com.company.ldap.LdapUserDetailsContextMapper"/>

    <bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.company.ldap.LdapAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

    <bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="com.company.ldap.LdapAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>

    <sec:http use-expressions="true"
              auto-config="false"
              create-session="never"
              entry-point-ref="entryPoint"
              authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">

        <sec:form-login
                login-processing-url="/login"
                authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
                username-parameter="username"
                password-parameter="password"
                login-page="/"/>

        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

        <sec:logout invalidate-session="true"
                    delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
                    logout-url="/secure/logout"
                    success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"/>

        <sec:csrf disabled="true"/>
        <sec:headers disabled="true"/>

    </sec:http>

    <sec:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
        <sec:ldap-authentication-provider user-search-filter="${ldap.search.filter}"
                                          user-context-mapper-ref="userDetailsContextMapper"/>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

First what you need to do is to define [LdapContextSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/support/LdapContextSource.html) and set all the approate values, for e.g. mine looks as follows:

```
ldap.url=ldap://ldap-host:389/
ldap.userdn=cn=some-cn,cn=Users,dc=dcname,dc=net
ldap.password=*******
ldap.base=ou=Users,ou=City,ou=Company,dc=dcname,dc=net
ldap.search.filter=sAMAccountName={0}
```

Then I had to create a couple of classes to handle success login, sucess logout, user mapping, etc..

For e.g. my Authentication Success Handler:

```
public class LdapAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/secure/user");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Which just forwards the request to `"/secure/user"` this URL after successful authentication. There I have Spring controller's method configured for this path to return some user details.

You also might need an EntryPoint to handle errors and UserContextMapper to get some user details from Ldap. This is up to you how going to implement [AuthenticationEntryPoint](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/AuthenticationEntryPoint.html) and [LdapUserDetailsMapper](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/LdapUserDetailsMapper.html)

Nothing special about the other configuration, just simple `form-login` and disabled CSRF and other security headers because I didn't need them for my application.

Please note that from Spring Security 4.0.0 you have to disable those headers yourself if you don't need them, becouse they are enabled by default while in all previous version, by default, they were disabled.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I have to add/make any changes in client side so that my client controller can know that it need to check from code written on server side? Also In my application I am using modal service of bootstrap for login page, so in my application /login is not generated in the url. Is it necessary to generated the login link in url or we can do authentication using the same setting by using modal service of bootstrap.

Comment: is it possible for you to add authenticate entry point code and ldapuserdetailsmapper code here has I am new in java spring.